# Can't upgrade from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2017 - "No Features found"

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, upgrade, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to upgrade from SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 Express to SQL Server 2017 Express and failing badly :(

The current install is SQL Server 2008 R2 32-bit, I had to download the SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 update in 32-bit to get SQL Server 2017 Express installer to run. Which was fine. But all I'm getting is this error now:

[image: Error Message]

All I could find online is you need the 32-bit version to upgrade the 32-bit version but there is only one installer provided from Microsoft and it worked on another machine just fine.

I tried downloading media again as ISO, and tried advanced version installation. Basically every installer you can download except standalone DB

Please any help much appreciated.

Comment: There is no 32bit version of SQL Server 2017. You won't be able to upgrade a 2008 32bit version to a 64bit 2017 version.

Comment: Oh crap, so there is no way to upgrade 32-bit 2008 to 2017 at all? Can you convert it to 64-bit without screwing up the data?

Comment: Personally, considering the rift between 2008 and 2017 anyway, I would backup the databases, script out the `master` and `msdb` properties you need to retain and restore them (the DBs) and run the scripts on the 2017 instance.

Comment: Is this 64-bit? "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1790.0 (Intel X86)   Apr 22 2011 12:01:59   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (WOW64) (Hypervisor) "

Comment: No. X86 is 32 bit. 64bit shows as X64.

Comment: Since you have SQL Express, it's unlikley you have jobs, SSIS packages, or anything particaulrly complex. As @Larnu says, just install a new instance and backup/restore your DB over.

Comment: Okay thanks, I guess I have to rebuild the database and migrate the data over :(